# Angular - Got type mismatch error while using for-in loop

Tags: angular, typescript

After selecting a particular date on the DOM calendar, I want to display if the date is Sunday or not. So I implement the logic something like this :

```js
SunValue = [
  {sunUn : false},
  {sunUn2 : false}
]

sunday(){

  let dt = new Date(_moment(this.Model.unloadingDate.value).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString())
  let dt2 = new Date(_moment(this.Model.receiptDate.value).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString())

  let dayobj = {
    day1: dt.getDay(),
    day2: dt2.getDay()
  }
  for(const key in dayobj){
    if(dayobj[key] == 0){
      //some logic here
    }
  }
}
```

But in the for-in loop it says:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ day1: number; day2: number; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ day1: number; day2: number; }'
> const key: string

and I cant use the type annotation here. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Cast `obj` as `any` type

```js
if ((dayobj as any)[key] == 0) {
  //some logic here
}
```

---

### Solution 2: Define type for `dayObj`

```js
let dayobj: {[key:string]: number} = {
  day1: dt.getDay(),
  day2: dt2.getDay(),
};
```

[Sample Solutions on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-djt2xb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I prefer the 2nd solution.